# Convert array<System:Byte>^ to Mat

Tags: opencv, c++-cli, mat

How do I convert an `array<System:Byte>^` to a `Mat` in openCV. I am being passed a `array<System:Byte>^` in c++/cli, but I need to convert it to `Mat` to be able to read it and display it.

Comment: What data does your byte array contain? Is it just the matrix data, or is it the full Mat object, including data members such as `Mat->rows` & `Mat->cols`?

Comment: It is the jpeg image data, so just the matrix data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use constructor `Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)`. The conversion may look like this.

```
void byteArray2Mat(array<System::Byte>^ byteArray, cv::Mat &output)
{
    pin_ptr<System::Byte> p = &byteArray[0];
    unsigned char* pby = p;
    char* pch = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pby);

    // assuming your input array has 2 dimensions.
    int rows = byteArray->GetLength(0);
    int cols = byteArray->GetLength(1);
    output = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC1, (void*)pch)
}
```

I don't have c++/CLI to test the program and this may not be most efficient method. At least it should give you an idea on how to get started.